Getting 403 Permission Error with MSGraph Sharepoint API Python
I am trying to move sharepoint files, using the patch function from the MSGraph method, to another destination folder, but for some reason I keep getting the error when trying to compute the line, result = await self.user_client.drives.by_drive_id(parent_drive_id).items.by_drive_item_id(src_item_id).patch(request_body) :
msgraph.generated.models.o_data_errors.o_data_error.ODataError:
        APIError
        Code: 403
        message: None
        error: MainError(additional_data={}, code='accessDenied', details=None, inner_error=InnerError(additional_data={}, client_request_id='XXXX', date=DateTime(2024, 5, 23, 8, 5, 34, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), odata_type=None, request_id='XXXX'), message='Access denied', target=None)

I think the issue lies in how I set up the request_body and/or how I defined the drive/item id's in the results variable.
Does anyone have an idea what I might have done incorrectly? I also have the correct rights to move/write/read files in the corresponding Sharepoint site. Am I perhaps using the incorrect destination parent folder id in the request_body? If so, does anyone know how to get the correct id? Thank u in advance :)
    async def _move_sharepoint_file(self, url, site_name, src_drive_path, file_name, dst_site_name, dst_drive_path, new_file_name=None):
    # Check permissions and verify authentication - ensure proper scopes are included in token
    
    # Get source site and its drive items
        sites = await self.user_client.sites.with_url(url).get()
        src_site_id = None
        dst_site_id = None
        
        for site in sites.value:
            print(site.name)
            if site.name == site_name:
                src_site_id = site.id
            if site.name == dst_site_name:
                dst_site_id = site.id
        
        # if src_site_id is None:
        #     raise ValueError(f"Source site with name '{site_name}' not found")
        # if dst_site_id is None:
        #     raise ValueError(f"Destination site with name '{dst_site_name}' not found")

        query_params = ItemsRequestBuilder.ItemsRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
            filter = True
        )

        request_configuration = ItemsRequestBuilder.ItemsRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration(
            query_parameters = query_params,
        )
        
        path_list = src_drive_path.replace("\\", "/").split('/')
        print(path_list)
        drive_items = await self.user_client.drives.by_drive_id(src_site_id).items.get(request_configuration=request_configuration)
        drive_items = drive_items.value
        
        partial_dir = ""
        print(f"path_list: {path_list}")
        for dir in path_list:
            if len(path_list) == 1 and path_list[0] == "":
                
                correct_drive_items = drive_items
                
                break
            else:
                partial_dir += f"/{dir}"
            print(f"partial_dir: {partial_dir}") if self.verbose else None
            [print(f"drive: {drive.name}") for drive in drive_items] if self.verbose else None
            print() if self.verbose else None
            for drive_item in drive_items:
                if drive_item.name == dir:
                    break
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"Drive with name '{partial_dir}' not found")
            
            drive_id = drive_item.id
            drive_items = await self.user_client.drives.by_drive_id(src_site_id).items.by_drive_item_id(drive_id).children.get()
            drive_items = drive_items.value
            
            correct_drive_items = []
            for drive_item in drive_items:
                print(f"drive_item.name: {drive_item.name}") if self.verbose else None
                parent_path = drive_item.parent_reference.path
                print(f"drive_item.parent_reference.path: {drive_item.parent_reference.path}") if self.verbose else None
                if parent_path.endswith(partial_dir):
                    correct_drive_items.append(drive_item)
                    print(f"YES") if self.verbose else None
        drives = correct_drive_items
        drives = [drive for drive in drives if drive.name in file_name]
        if len(drives) == 0:    
            raise ValueError(f"Drive with name '{file_name}' not found")
        
        src_item_id = drives[0].id
        parent_drive_id = drives[0].parent_reference.drive_id
        print(parent_drive_id)

        # Find the source item
        #src_item_id = await self.get_item_id(src_site_id, src_drive_path, file_name)

        # Get destination folder ID
        dst_drive_items = await self.user_client.drives.by_drive_id(dst_site_id).items.get(request_configuration=request_configuration)
        dst_folder_id = None
        for drive_item in dst_drive_items.value:
            if drive_item.name == dst_drive_path.split('/')[-1]:
                dst_folder_id = drive_item.id
                
                parent_dst_id = drive_item.parent_reference.drive_id
                print("Not none")
                break
        
        
        if src_item_id is None:
            raise ValueError(f"Item with name '{file_name}' in path '{src_drive_path}' not found")
        if dst_folder_id is None:
            raise ValueError(f"Destination folder '{dst_drive_path}' not found")

        # Get source drive ID
        src_drive_items = await self.user_client.drives.by_drive_id(src_site_id).items.get(request_configuration=request_configuration)
        src_drive_id = None
        for drive_item in src_drive_items.value:
            if drive_item.name == src_drive_path:
                src_drive_id = drive_item.id
                break
        
        if src_drive_id is None:
            raise ValueError(f"Source drive '{src_drive_path}' not found")

       
       
        request_body = DriveItem(
            parent_reference = ItemReference(
                site_id= dst_site_id,
                id = dst_folder_id,
            ),
            name ="new-item-name.pdf",
        )
        
        result = await self.user_client.drives.by_drive_id(parent_drive_id).items.by_drive_item_id(src_item_id).patch(request_body)
        
        if result.is_success:
            print("File moved successfully.")
            return result.content
        else:
            print(f"Failed to move file. Status code: {result.status_code}")
            return None

I have tried several combinations of drive and item id's, because I thought that would be the issue. But everytime I get the same error. The (almost) same method for downloading a Sharepoint file does work using MSGraph and I do have the correct rights in Azure but also in Sharepoint for the corresponding file.

As the error 403 access denied suggests that the issue is with token. May I know what kind of application you are building? Is it daemon application or a delegated application? What scopes have you added? How are you getting the token? Which account are you using, is it Microsoft account or Work/school account? Please also try using graph explorer and see if you are getting the results or not.

@ShivaKeshavVarma Currently when I run the main function, it directs me to a microsoft site where I have to manually log in (when everything works we are planning to make it a daemon application). But I am currently trying to build an application that moves certain files in Sharepoint based on certain input. The microsoft account I use is a Work/School account. The same token works when trying to download files from Sharepoint.

Would you tell me whether your issue has been resolved or have any update? If you have any questions or progress, you can contact me in time.
